# What do I need to use a Nikon charger in power outlets when traveling in Europe?

Tags: nikon, travel, charger, power-supply

I have a Nikon D3100 which I am using in India.

I'll be travelling to Europe (France/Switzerland/Italy, Austria) and wanted to know if the same charger can be used as it is in these countries (for pin compatibility as well as voltage).

The charger that I use currently in India looks like below;
[image]

Would I need any adapter to use in European countries ?

Answer (score 6):

In Europe the voltage is 230v, so if your adapter operates outside the 220-240v range you have to buy some kind of adapter doing the conversion.

Also, Italy, France, Switzerland and Austria all have different power outlet shapes, but there is a common plug called "Europlug" which works on all four countries ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug ). Get an adapter converting to that type.

For future reference, other countries, etc. refer to this wikipedia page which summarizes all the possible types: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: Thx...I have added the image of the charger I use in India...So looking at it, could you let me know if I could use the same in the Europeean countries I have mentioned without any issue ?

Comment: You can use the same adapter in European countries. All you will need is a converter that convert the Flat plug you have on the charger to the European standard. See link on Europlug in the answer

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this charger will work. You can see from the specifications in the picture that it will accept a range of voltage from 100 to 240V. That includes Japan on the lowest side, and the US / North America at 110, and Europe at 230V.

You will just need a physical plug adapter, which you can get pretty much anywhere. The countries you are visiting all have slightly different standards, but there is a design called the "europlug" which will work pretty much everywhere in continental Europe. Check the packaging / documentation of the plug adapter you buy — it will list where it will work.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see the charger has the two pin plug, so that is compatible with the europlug used in most european countries, including all the ones you listed.

You might stumble on an older socket installation for example in Italy, but they have the same current so you only need a converter for those. Modern sockets are compatible with both older and newer standards, so there you have no problem.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: The standard plug of Italy is the Europlug with an additional pin, so if the charger is Europlug compatible, he won't have any problems finding a socket.

Comment: @MarcoMp: Yes, that's the current standard, but there may be installations with the older standard.

Comment: Thx...I have added the image of the charger I use in India...So looking at it, could you let me know if I could use the same in the Europeean countries I have mentioned without any issue ?

Comment: @Guffa: The older standard is simply a Europlug as itself (the change in the years was the addition of the earth pin). We *have* two different sockets (10A which is the Europlug and 16A which is meant for higher power loads) but I've never seen a location with 16A sockets and no 10A sockets around, while the opposite is a lot more common (practically every common appliance uses the 10A one).

Comment: @testndtv: The currency and frequency range of the charger is right. The plug doesn't look at all what I see described as the standard in India, rather like a US plug. Do you have a converter to the two-pin plug used in India? Otherwise you will need a converter to use it in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the voltages, or in the case of this kind of equipment look for a **CE mark** which confirms that a device is certified to be compatible with the appropriate EU standards.  I've ringed it for ease of identification.

[image: Nikon charger with CE Mark highlighted]

You will still require some kind of socket adapter depending on which country you're visiting.  Adapters are usually available at most airports if you don't manage to get them before you leave.

While voltages are technically harmonised to 230v typically the UK is 240v while the rest of mainland Europe is typically 220v.  It's not a problem since both lie in the 230v -6%/+10% tolerance (216-253v or thereabouts) mandated by the EU standard.

Answer (score 0):

In Europe, the charger MH-24 comes whith an adapter like this picture: [image] Unfortunately, you can't buy it separately.

But, this one work too, it's that you need: [Electric Adapter USA->EU](http://amzn.com/B002NLGCL0) (In Amazon).

Or this one, more cheap, in DX: [Cheap Universal EU Travel AC Power Adapter Plugs (2-Piece / 125~250V)](http://dx.com/p/universal-eu-travel-ac-power-adapter-plugs-2-pack-55710#.Ut1BX9K0rGg)